# angularjs: forEach in ng-click

Tags: angularjs, for-loop

I have a problem with implementing "select All" feature for simple list:

Controller:

```
$scope.numbers = [{v:1},{v:2},{v:3},{v:4}];
```

Template:

```
<a href="" ng-click="numbers.forEach(function(v) {v.selected=true;});">select All</a>
<p ng-repeat='n in numbers'>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="n.selected">
    Label: {{ n.v }}
  </label>
</p>
```

It seems angular parser cannot process the ng-click statement:

> Error: [$parse:syntax]
>   (...) 
>   at relational (angular.min.js:234) 
>      at r.equality (angular.min.js:233) 
>      at r.logicalAND (angular.min.js:233) "<a href="" ng-click="numbers.forEach(function(v) {v.selected=true;});">"

Plunker demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/6OZP02SZ5ZYa0iO4PBY3?p=preview

Can I implement that just in the html template or have to use the controller method?

**Edit**: Controller method works fine, I'm just still interested why in-place code doesn't parse though?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `angular.forEach(numbers, function(v) {v.selected=true;});`?

Comment: @LioraHaydont I had already tried that, the same error: at r.logicalAND (VM1962 angular.min.js:233) "<a href="" ng-click="angular.forEach(number, function(v) {v.selected=true})">"

Comment: @jkalamarz          onclick is an javascript event, so it can call function in javascript window object.

ng-click is an angular directive, which can only call functions which is available in the $scope.

Comment: Did you follow the error link angular gave you?  https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20unexpected,%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=29&p3=numbers.forEach(function(v)%20%7Bv.selected%3Dtrue%7D)&p4=%7Bv.selected%3Dtrue%7Dsays that the curly bracket is illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below, `numbers.forEach(function(v) {v.selected=true;});` is wrong will throw the error because numbers doesn't have `forEach` menthod and anonymous function will not work in `ng-click`

This is the best way to perform select all

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="all">
        Select All
      </label>
    <p ng-repeat='n in numbers'>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="all">
        Label: {{ n.v }}
      </label>
    </p>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = [{v:1},{v:2},{v:3},{v:4}];
});
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/mspj0z65/1/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <a href="" ng-click="loop">select All</a>
    <p ng-repeat='n in numbers'>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="n.selected">
        Label: {{ n.v }}
      </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

**Angular script:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = [{v:1},{v:2},{v:3},{v:4}];
  $scope.loop = function(){
    angular.forEach(numbers, function(v) {
      v.selected=true;
    });
  }
});
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/mspj0z65/

Comment: Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 38 of the expression [angular.forEach(numbers, function(v) {v.selected=true;});] starting at [{v.selected=true;});].

Comment: Refer the demo URL. Anonymous function block will not work in `ng-click`

Answer (score 0):

It is better implements the method on controller as:

```
$scope.selectAll=function() {
        $scope.numbers.forEach(function(v) {
          v.selected=true
        });
      }
```

and in view use `ng-click="selecAll()"`

Let your view as simple as posible and make the code more readable ans ease to 
understand by third parties or own in the future.

I recomend take a view to [John Papa Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

Comment: +1 for keeping logic out of the template.  @jkalamarz: You should program to an interface, not an implementation.